# First order condition in constrained optimization: Alternative characterization via normal cones

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following constrained optimization:
Min $f(x)$, $x\in C\subset R^n$, where C is convex.

We know that one characterization of a local minimum (necessary condition) is the following:
STANDARD CHARACTERIZATION:
If $a$ is a local minimum, then $\langle x-a,\nabla f(a)\rangle  \geq 0 \:\: \forall x\in \bar C$

I saw in paper that an alternative condition was used:

ALTERNATIVE CHARACTERIZATION:

If $a$ is a local minimum, then $\langle x-a,\nabla f(x)\rangle  \geq 0 \:\: \forall x\in \bar C$
I wasn't able to convince myself that this is true. Can anyone comment on this alternative definition?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the paper.

Comment: The function $f$ is convex?

Comment: no need for $f$ to be convex, only $C^1$, and this is the steepest descent algorithm : when you follow the steepest descent direction (i.e. $- \nabla f(x)$) you'll arrive at a local minimum (or at the border of the domain). and there are two zones of influence of a local minimum $a$ : the connected subset containing  all the points such that $< x-a,\nabla f(x) > \ \ \ge 0$, and the subset containing the points such that when following the steepest gradient flow, you'll arrive at $a$ (think to a valley climbing in spiral and surrounded by big mountains)

Answer (score 1):

If the function $f$ is convex, its gradient is monotone,
hence,
$$\langle x - y, \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\rangle \ge 0.$$
You can apply this with $y = a$ and this shows that
$$\langle x -a, \nabla f(a) \rangle \ge 0 \quad\forall x \in \bar C$$
implies
$$\langle x -a, \nabla f(x) \rangle \ge 0 \quad\forall x \in \bar C.$$